# FastAPI - Repeat PUT-Endpoint every X seconds

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

I want to execute a PUT-Endpoint every 15 seconds.
I already tried to use `repeated_task` from `fastapi_utils.tasks`, but when I implemented it this way:

```
@app.put('/fuellstand', response_model=Fuellstand)
@app.on_event("startup")
@repeat_every(seconds=5)
def return_fuellstand():
    liste = get_fuellstand(lanes)

    return Fuellstand(
        __root__=liste
    )
```

I just got `Null`, when executing the endpoint via the openapi-docs.
I also tried to print out something to see, if the repetition works, but I also didn't got any message in the console.

Is this the right way to implement `repeated_task`?

Comment: Don't define your repeating function as both an endpoint and a repeating task, separate those out to different functionalities. Your `put` endpoint can call that function instead, if necessary, but otherwise there is no `put` context in a repeating task

Comment: Okay I creted a function for the repeated task. This function gets called from the enpoint. When I print out the content in the console it seems to work, but when executing the endpoint via the openapi-docs I get the following error: `pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Fuellstand __root__ value is not a valid list (type=type_error.list)`. 
Is the endpoint then not supposed to work when manually executing it?

Comment: It's complaining that whatever you're returning from your `get_load_factor` function can't be serialized automagically - i.e. it's not a value that can be directly converted to JSON or serialized as a Pydantic model. Since you haven't specified what you're returning from `Load_Factor`, it's hard to say anything in particular. My suggestion was to switch the functionality around, make the controller call the function, not the function call the controller.

Comment: Gotcha! I edited my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73361143/5904672). Now I can also execute the endpoint. Is it now the way you meant?

Comment: That reads far better, yes - and if it works properly, that's a bonus :-)

Comment: Nice! Yes it works and it reads better ;)

Answer (score 2):

I now created a additional function that gets executed repeatedly:

```
@app.put('/loadFactor', response_model=Load_Factor)
def put_load_factor():
    load_factor = get_load_factor(lanes)

    return Load_Factor(
        __root__ = load_factor
    )

@app.on_event("startup")
@repeat_every(seconds=15)
def return_load_factor():
    put_load_factor()
```